# materialize validation css top/left offset

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have a page using materialize framework, with a select field:

```
  .input-field
    Region(s)
    = select_tag 'user[region_ids][]', options_for_select(@regions_list), :multiple => true, :class => %w(toHide regionSelector validate), :required => true
    %label{ for: "user[region_ids][]" } The region is required
```

[image]

The validation popup is aligned to the top-left corner of input-field, but I'd like it to be aligned to bottom-left or bottom-center. How would I make that change?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using the latest version of Materialize? This was supposed to be fixed in the v0.100.2 release, as seen here: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/commit/dbdd869bc929cf124757eb22d3694dc5d746c7e0

Comment: Jonny, I think you're right... I am unable to update the version of materialize on that project, but doing so would perhaps fix the issue. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for letting me know. I spent a few minutes trying to replicate your environment and couldn't duplicate the issue on the latest version of Materialize. I wish you the best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to using a pre v0.100.2 version of Materialize. The latest version of Materialize and its associated documentation can be found here: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize